# Increment using arrow key

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrow-keys

I have a situation where I need to be able to add an 'active' depending if I hit the left arrow key or right arrow key. Essentialy I am just tabbing through a menu. I keep getting undefined returned when I am trying to set my state.

Erro: 'Cannot read property 'cursor' of undefined'

Menu.js

```
...

class Menu extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    //set active-state to name of button label
    this.state = {
      activeTab: this.props.children[0].props.label,
      cursor: 0,
    };
  }
  ...
```

Comment: Please state the *exact* error you're getting, and at which line it is happening.

Comment: Just updated. Its happening in the 'handleKeyDown' method

Comment: try to debug by printing your cursor variable on the console

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind `handleKeyDown()` to the class like this:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    //set active-state to name of button label
    this.state = {
      activeTab: this.props.children[0].props.label,
      cursor: 0,
    };

    // bind the 'this' of the class to the function so this.state can be reached
    this.handleKeyDown = this.handleKeyDown.bind(this); 
  }
```

Basically, whenever you need to work with a class method that needs to use class variable like `this.state`, you need to bind 'this' to the function. Refer to React Docs [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html)

Comment: Doesn’t work. I’m pretty sure a key code has to be binded to the document

Comment: The part i gave you is necessary for handleKeyDown to work with this.state. Also for onClickTabItem  and onClick on button.js. Could you paste the full error message you get?

Comment: It’s listed in the title. “Arrow Key”

Comment: Are you still getting the error  'Cannot read property 'cursor' of undefined' once you put the bindings?

Comment: @dabishan The error points to `prevState` being undefined, which is really really weird, given that it's the parameter of the function. Your answer assumes the common `this` problem, which I don't think is the issue here.

Comment: Have you tried using the shorthand way? `this.setState({cursor: this.state.cursor - 1})` and `this.setState({cursor: this.state.cursor  + 1})`